# Get is_purchasable hook working for Woocommerce product variations too

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, date-range

I have made 2 custom product fields - availability - since when/until when. So if the current date is between these set availability dates then product is purchasable, else - it's not. Everything works perfectly however only until I post a product with a variations. Then it's like product variations ignore these custom availability fields/values and still let to add variations to cart even if current date is not between set availability dates.

```
function hide_product_if_unavailable( $is_purchasable, $object ) {

  $date_from = get_post_meta( $object->get_id(), '_availability_schedule_dates_from' );
  $date_to = get_post_meta( $object->get_id(), '_availability_schedule_dates_to' );
  $current_date = current_time('timestamp');

  if ( strlen($date_from[0]) !== 0 ) {

    if ( ( $current_date >= (int)$date_from[0] ) && ( $current_date <= (int)$date_to[0] ) ) {

      return true;

    } else {

      return false;

    }

  } else {

    # Let adding product to cart if Availability fields was not set at all
    return true;

  }

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'hide_product_if_unavailable', 10, 2 );
```

I tried to add another filter just below `woocommerce_is_purchasable`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'hide_product_if_unavailable', 10, 2 );
```

But variations still ignore availability fields.

Comment: It's set for product, not for each product's variation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this revisited code for all product types (including product variations) :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'purchasable_product_date_range', 20, 2 );
function purchasable_product_date_range( $purchasable, $product ) {
    $date_from = (int) get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_availability_schedule_dates_from', true );
    $date_to = (int) get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_availability_schedule_dates_to', true );
    if( empty($date_from) ||  empty($date_to) )
        return $purchasable; // Exit (fields are not set)

    $current_date = (int) current_time('timestamp');
    if( ! ( $current_date >= $date_from && $current_date <= $date_to ) )
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}
```

To make **product variation** work you need to get **the parent product ID**, because your variations don't have this date range custom fields:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'purchasable_variation_date_range', 20, 2 );
function purchasable_variation_date_range( $purchasable, $product ) {
    $date_from = (int) get_post_meta( $product->get_parent_id(), '_availability_schedule_dates_from', true );
    $date_to = (int) get_post_meta( $product->get_parent_id(), '_availability_schedule_dates_to', true );
    if( empty($date_from) ||  empty($date_to) )
        return $purchasable; // Exit (fields are not set)

    $current_date = (int) current_time('timestamp');
    if( ! ( $current_date >= $date_from && $current_date <= $date_to ) )
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: @fuji I have try to merge everything in one, using both hooks on the same function with additional conditions, but it was not working… So this is the best option for the moment.