# Make is_purchasable hook work with variations and product tags In Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

I'm trying to prevent that visitors buying certain products based on product tags.

I'm using `'woocommerce_is_purchasable'` woocommerce filter but it doesn't work with variable products.

This is my code:

```
    function remove_add_to_cart_for_tag_id ( $purchasable, $product ){

    if( $product->get_tag_ids() == array(181)) {

      $purchasable = false;

    } else {
      return $purchasable;
    }

    if ( $purchasable && $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $purchasable = $product->parent->is_purchasable();
    }

    return $purchasable;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_for_tag_id', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_for_tag_id', 10, 2 );
```

I've based my code on this example: [Get is_purchasable hook working for Woocommerce product variations too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473854)

Comment: what do you mean by part 2 in your title?

Comment: @Abdul another similar question has already been asked, I have already referenced that question but I can not solve my problem in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some errors and mistakes in your code. Try the following instead *(to make it work with product variations too)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_for_tag_id', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_for_tag_id', 10, 2 );
function remove_add_to_cart_for_tag_id ( $purchasable, $product ){
    // For product variations (from variable products)
    if ( $product->is_type('variation') ){
        $parent = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() );
        $tag_ids = $parent->get_tag_ids(); 
    } 
    // For other product types
    else {
        $tag_ids = $product->get_tag_ids();
    }

    if( in_array( 181, $tag_ids ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work now.

Comment: Loic TheAztec It seems that the code should work perfectly but the result is the same, it becomes impossible to buy simple products but variable products can still be purchased. Is there another way to avoid buying certain products, identified by a tag?

Comment: @Noe_Mares Sorry But there is something else interacting in your case. Note that Is_purchasable works for each variation of a variable product, not globally for the variable product.

Comment: Thank you @Loic TheAztec when I find a solution, I will publish it here.

Comment: Yes of course. The theme that I am using replaces many native functions of woocommerce, there should be the problem. Thank you @LoicTheAztec

Comment: The code now works perfectly !!! There was a problem of incompatibility with my theme but I have already solved it. Your code, today, is ideal for other people who have the same problem. Thanks.